# regexp to include underscore

Tags: regex, r, grepl

I'm new to using to regexp. I have the following:

```
  files = c("apple_2014_10_17.csv",
          "apple_2014_10_18.csv",
          "applepie_2014_10_17.csv",
          "applepie_2014_10_18.csv")
```

I am looking to return **only**:

```
apple_2014_10_17.csv
apple_2014_10_18.csv
```

and **NOT** return:

```
applepie_2014_10_17.csv
applepie_2014_10_18.csv
```

I'm using the following regexp

```
grepl("apple_*", files)
```

But it returns all the files. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could simply remove the `*` quantifier. The problem is that this quantifer means "zero or more" times and will match `apple` in all vector elements whether you have an underscore that precedes or not.

```
files[grepl('apple_', files)]
# [1] "apple_2014_10_17.csv" "apple_2014_10_18.csv"
```

Or you could retain the quantifier and just place a dot `.` in front of it. This way `apple_` is matched literally and then the preceding token (`.` *any single character*) is matched "zero or more" times instead.

```
files[grepl('apple_.*', files)]
# [1] "apple_2014_10_17.csv" "apple_2014_10_18.csv"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `value` argument in `grep` and not have to subset `files`.  The `fixed` argument of `grep` (and `grepl`) will make the matching exact and since this does not pass through the regex engine often times will make it faster.

```
grep("apple_", files, value = TRUE, fixed = TRUE)
# [1] "apple_2014_10_17.csv" "apple_2014_10_18.csv"
```

Or easier might be to use the `invert` argument and search for "pie", returning the opposite matches.

```
grep("pie", files, value = TRUE, invert = TRUE)
# [1] "apple_2014_10_17.csv" "apple_2014_10_18.csv"
```

Note that if you're searching for files in a directory, you can also try

```
list.files(pattern = "apple_")
```